# SVM plot for a non-linear decision boundary

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to plot SVM decision boundary which separates two classes, cancerous and non-cancerous. However, it's displaying a plot which is far from what I wanted. I wanted it to look like this:

[image]
or anything that shows the points are scattered. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

autism = pd.read_csv('predictions.csv')


# Fit Support Vector Machine Classifier
X = autism[['TARGET','Predictions']]
y = autism['Predictions']

clf = svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='rbf', gamma=0.8)
clf.fit(X.values, y.values) 

# Plot Decision Region using mlxtend's awesome plotting function
plot_decision_regions(X=X.values, 
                      y=y.values,
                      clf=clf, 
                      legend=2)

# Update plot object with X/Y axis labels and Figure Title
plt.xlabel(X.columns[0], size=14)
plt.ylabel(X.columns[1], size=14)
plt.title('SVM Decision Region Boundary', size=16)
plt.show()
```

But I got a weird looking plot:

[image]

You can find the csv file here [predictions.csv](https://github.com/falady/svm_classification.git)

Comment: @desertnaut no i did not make a mistake in the input file. i purposely wanted to try that file (`predictions.csv`) because I couldn't work out with the one in my repo. But i will have a try if you could just answer my question in the comment?

Comment: As said, what you are trying to do here dies not make any sense at all. And I have already answered your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sound a little confused...

Your `predictions.csv` looks like:

```
TARGET  Predictions
     1  0
     0  0
     0  0
     0  0
```

and, as I guess the column names imply, it contains the ground truth (`TARGET`) and the `Predictions` of some (?) model already run.

Given that, what you are doing in your posted code makes absolutely **no sense** at all: you are using both these columns as features in your `X` in order to predict your `y`, which is... exactly one of these same columns (`Predictions`), already contained in your `X`...

Your plot looks "strange" simply because what you have plotted are **not** your data points, and the `X` and `y` data you show here are *not* the data that should be used for fitting your classifier.

I am further puzzled because, in your linked repo, you have indeed the correct procedure in your script:

```
autism = pd.read_csv('10-features-uns.csv')

x = autism.drop(['TARGET'], axis = 1)  
y = autism['TARGET']
x_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.30, random_state=1)
```

i.e. reading your features and labels from `10-features-uns.csv`, and certainly **not** from `predictions.csv`, as you are inexplicably trying to do here...

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the column names. So.. you're trying to say that I should use the `10-features-uns.csv` data instead for my problem above and use that other script in my repo?

Comment: @Falady Exactly!